# On Galois' criterion for resolvents

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field, $f(x) = 0$ an algebraic equation over $K$ of degree $n \ge 2$ with only simple roots $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$, and $L \mathrel{:=} K[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ the splitting field of this equation over $K$. Any $y \in L$ then has a representation
$$y = P(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)\label{1}\tag{1}$$
with $P = P(X_1, \dotsc, X_n) \in K[X_1, \dotsc, X_n]$ a polynomial in the $n$ indeterminates $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ over $K$. Such an element is also called a *rational function of the roots* — this being *a priori* a quotient $Q(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)/R(x_1,\dotsc, x_n)$, but such an expression can always be rewritten as a polynomial $P(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ —. A *resolvent* for the equation $f(x) = 0$ is then an expression $t = P(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ having, in classical parlance, the property that any rational function of the roots can be expressed as a rational function of $t$, or being, in modern terminology, a *primitive element* of the field extension $L:K$ (for this and what follows see [1]).

This notion goes back to Lagrange and Galois, and was taken by the latter as the point of departure of his theory of the solvability of equations (later vigorously exorcised by Dedekind and Artin, making the theory questionably more elegant and unquestionably much more impenetrable). The point of departure for obtaining, in return, such a resolvent, was the following observation.
Fix once and for all an enumeration of the roots as $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$.
Any permutation $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n$ operates on the polynomials
$P \in K[X_1, \dotsc, X_n]$ via $P \mapsto P^{\sigma}$ with
$$P^{\sigma}(X_1, \dotsc, X_n) \mathrel{:=} P(X_{\sigma(1)},  \dotsc, X_{\sigma(1)}).$$
Thus to any $y \in L$ with a given representation \eqref{1} there
is attached a bunch of at most $n!$ different values $y^{\sigma} \mathrel{:=} P^{\sigma}(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$. There are two basic claims:

- (C1) If the values $t^{\sigma}$ are pairwise different, so that there are
  exactly $n!$ different ones, then $t$ is a resolvent;
- (C2) for every degree $d \ge 1$ (and even only $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients),
  the generic polynomial $P$ gives $t = P(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ satisfying
  (C1), thus yielding a resolvent.

Here, "generic" means "not satisfying a certain nontrivial polynomial relation".

Now the condition (C1) is initially only sufficient, and the property of being
a resolvent does not make use of the special representation \eqref{1}, so it is *a priori* possible that there is a representation $t = Q(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ *not*
satisfying (C2) with $t$ still being a resolvent.

Question:

> Can this happen?

[1] Edwards, H.M.,
*Galois  Theory*
(Graduate Texts in Mathematics 101). Springer 1984

Comment: Despite your definition, I don't know what "generic" means.  *Which* relation is "a certain nontrivial polynomial relation"?  What does it mean to speak of whether a polynomial (which is what you are calling generic) satisfies a polynomial relation?

Comment: Also, since you edited it back in you obviously want it, so I apologise for an edit that went against your intentions; but "a bunch of at most $n!$ different values" is not usual English.    Usually one would say something like "a bunch of different values, at most $n!$" or just "at most $n!$ different values".

Comment: Hopefully useful reference on non-modern Galois Theory, https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7116

Comment: (C1) is only necessary for a primitive element when $n!$ is the degree of the extension $L/K$.  But there are examples of degree $3$ Galois extensions, and $n!$ never equals $3$.

Comment: Let $K=L=\mathbb{Q}$ and take $f(x)=x(x-1)$.  Thus, the two roots can be ordered as $x_1=0,x_2=1$.  **Any polynomial** $Q(X_1,X_2)$ will yield a primitive element for this extension when we evaluate at $x_1,x_2$.